# Eclipse build path is incorrect using maven

Tags: maven, webobjects

I am working on to run the WebObjects project using maven. I build and run the project successfully but the problem is that the execution directory path is from build folder, not target folder. For example: - `X:\WOMavenProject\ProjectName\build\ProjectName.woa\....`. But it should be target in place of `build`.

Answer (score 0):

Is maven building the project, or are you getting it invoked with maven? The phrase "I am working on to run the ... project" is not clear.

If the WOLips Incremental Builder is being used to build the project, it will pu the build products into the build directory.

When I use the Ant Builder, it builds into dist.

Presumably you have installed the Maven Builder. I assume here is one, but I have never used it. How is it configured? Does the Builder allow you to specify where the build products will appear?